# Moving files from different folders on an FTP server to local server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

In an FTP location I have many folders under `Data` like

```
Data
 | -- Folder1
 | -- Folder2
 | -- Folder3
```

In all these folders I have text files. I need to move all the text files from all the folders to my local SQL Server server.

I am able to transfer only one at a time, I need to move all the files in one operation.

Comment: Are you saying you need an SQL statement to iterate through the folder structure and FTP get each file?

Comment: So why don't you use the SSIS FTP task?

Comment: i tried using ftp task but able to get all the files under one folder here i have many folders.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but the SSIS FTP task is quite limited; my usual approach to tasks like this is to write an external script and call it from the package. If I wanted to keep all code inside the package I would use a Script Task. In my opinion, just because you're using SSIS it doesn't mean that you should try to use native SSIS components for every task; it's often easier just to call a stored procedure or an external script to do something, and use the package for control-of-flow, logging etc.